# Sorting structures from a file alphabetically in C

Tags: c, sorting, structure

It is necessary to make sorting of structures on a field (char last_name [256];) structures Pers
and display the user in the console.
How to do it?
Thank you in advance.

There is such a structure (with nested):

```
struct Pers {
    int id;
    char first_name[256];
    char last_name[256];
    struct {
        int age;
        int status;
    } st;
} Pers;


struct Pers sw[2];
char i=0;
```

reading from a file and output looks like this:
Everything is displayed in the order of reading from the file

```
 FILE *file;
 file = fopen("1.txt", "r");
 while ( fscanf(file, "%d%s%s%d%d", &sw[i].id,sw[i].first_name,sw[i].last_name,&sw[i].st.age,&sw[i].st.status) != EOF) 
 {

     printf("%d %s %s %d %d\n", sw[i].id, sw[i].first_name, sw[i].last_name, sw[i].st.age, sw[i].st.status);
        i++;
 }

 fclose(file);
```

Comment: First of all I do hope you don't have more than two records in the file. Secondly, You should not only check if [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns `EOF`, what if the file is corrupted? I suggest reading *lines* (using e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)) and then attempt to parse the line with `sscanf`.

Comment: You may have a look for [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). It is rather "generic" - you have to provide your own function for comparison. Hence you can sort everything what is stored in an array (and has any kind of order). This is recommended with the assumption, the assignment does not require to implement a sort function on your own.

Comment: As for your problem, don't print in the loop. Instead only read in the loop, then [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) the array, and finally have a second loop where you print.

Comment: `fscanf (file, "%d%s%s%d%d",`   `%s` should specify a width else you have a buffer overrun vulnerability. `%255s`

Comment: Here you go, the [complete logic is here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-sort-array-names-strings/).

Comment: @Some programmer dude  have more, but all Horsch works except sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `qsort` from `stdlib` for sorting of your structures, you should implement function that compares two elements. And to compare strings `strcmp` from `string` is used.

Details are in the [references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).

Example for case when both `first_name` and `last_name` are used for sorting (`last_name` is the first for comparison):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  const struct Pers * first = (const struct Pers *) a;
  const struct Pers * second = (const struct Pers *) b;
  // compare last names and check result. can be also:
  // if( !strcmp(first->last_name, second->last_name) )
  if( 0 == strcmp(first->last_name, second->last_name) )
      // compare first names if last names are equal
      return strcmp(first->first_name, second->first_name);
  else
      return strcmp(first->last_name, second->last_name);
}
```

usage:

```cpp
    printf("Before sorting:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s %s %d %d\n",sw[i].id,sw[i].first_name,sw[i].last_name,sw[i].st.age,sw[i].st.status);
    }
    qsort (sw, 2, sizeof(struct Pers), compare);
    printf("After sorting:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s %s %d %d\n",sw[i].id,sw[i].first_name,sw[i].last_name,sw[i].st.age,sw[i].st.status);
    }
```

Results on my data:

```
Before sorting:
1 John Smith 33 1
2 Jack Smith 18 1
After sorting:
2 Jack Smith 18 1
1 John Smith 33 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And what if the structures in the file are greater than 2. And they are written on one element of the structure per line

Comment: If number of structures to sort is N (in your example it is `i`), you need: 1) `for(i = 0; i < N; i++)` , and 2) `qsort (sw, N, sizeof(struct Pers), compare)`. So you must count number N while reading from file. As I understand reading from file is not a topic of this post.